# unknown attribute Error in Rails 3 Nested Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `submission` and a nested model `attachment`

in `submission.rb`:

```
has_many :assets, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true
```

in `assets.rb` :

```
  attr_accessible :file_id, :attachment
  belongs_to :submission
  has_attached_file :attachment
```

in my `submission` controller:

```
def new
    @submission = Submission.new
    @asset = 2.times{ @submission.assets.build }

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @submission }
    end
  end

  def edit
    @submission = Submission.find(params[:id])
    @asset = 2.times{ @submission.assets.build }
  end
```

And I'm getting a `unknown attribute: submission_id` error.

What could possibly be wrong here.

I'm following the screencast here:
http://www.emersonlackey.com/article/rails-paperclip-multiple-file-uploads

Comment: Where is the error located exactly ? (which line)

Comment: Do you have a `submission_id` column on your `assets` table in your database?

Comment: @Shane, no, I didn't. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: @Sparda, this line: `@asset = 2.times{ @submission.assets.build }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems submission_id is not present in your assets table.

You have to generate asset model like:

```
rails generate model Asset submission_id:integer #rails 3
```

And then run:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate #rails 3
```

Comment: by adding a new column "submission_id" to the `assets` table solves this problem, thank you for the answer!